# jsp how to obtain a list of fmt:message keys with wildcards?

Tags: jsp, internationalization

I'm a complete jsp newbe, so please bear over with me, if this is a stupid question.

I have a dynamic range of locale keys like this:

```
default.someWordTable.dynamicKey.XXX = "Some string"
default.someWordTable.dynamicKey.YYY = "Some other string"
default.someWordTable.dynamicKey.ZZZ = "A third string"
etc. etc. (with no special logic to the keynames)
```

Normally I get the localized words like this:

```
<fmt:message key="someWordTable.dynamicKey.XXX" />
```

But if I don't know the subset of keys at codepoint, is there some way I can obtain a list or an iterator of all existing keys under a namespace? I'm hoping for something in the neighbourhood of this:

```
<ul>
    <fmt:forEach items="someWordTable.dynamicKey.*" var="nextKey">
        <li><fmt:message key="someWordTable.dynamicKey.nextKey" /></li>
    </fmt:forEach>
</ul>
```

or perhaps something like:

```
<fmt:getAllSubKeys key="someWordTable.dynamicKey" var="theKeys" />
<ul>
    <c:forEach items="theKeys" var="key">
        <li><fmt:message key="someWordTable.dynamic[key]"></li>
    </c:forEach>
</ul>
```

I hope I have managed to explain what I am looking for. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why you want to do that, but one thing I can tell you is, the [ResourceBundle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) class a method [keySet()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#keySet--) which returns a [Set<String>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) containing resource keys.
It is possible to assign the bundle to a variable:

```
<fmt:setBundle basename="com.example.messages" var="bundle"/>
```

Than you can use it in `<c:forEach>`:

```
<c:forEach items="{$bundle.keySet()}" var="key">
   <li><fmt:message key="{$key}"></li>
</c:forEach>
```

One thing to note here is, I haven't tested this code. I hope it's correct. I know for sure that you should be able to use Expression Language somewhat similar to this. At least it should be supported with Servlet 3.0+.

Comment: It looks just like what I was hoping for. Unfortunately it does not work. :(

It seems like {$bundle.keySet()} is never evaluated? If I try to c:out key in the forEach loop, it just contains:
    "{$bundle.keySet()}" (I guess it is just treated like a string?) 

You also missed an ending "/" in the fmt:message statement.

Comment: If you want to know what I'm trying to obtain, read here:
I have some tables of locale keys that comes from a system backoffice administrator module. Eventually it is our aim that the administrators running the backoffice module should be able to add new locale keys dynamically without my interference.

Comment: I need these strings to translate some ajax responses that can change without my interference too, so I want to embed all the strings into javascript, so they are accessible from js on ajax complete. So on load of the page, I want to loop through all keys under a given namespace, embedding them into a js hash. Unfortunately I can't know the exact keys nor the amount of them when executing my jsp.